# Docker compose up giving error no such file or dir. for .sh files in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run the docker container for web which has script `start.sh` file to start it, but `docker-compose up web` is giving an error.

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/home/app/start.sh\": stat /home/app/start.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

By the following command it shows the `start.sh` is present in the docker image

```
docker run -it web bin/bash
```

***docker-compose.yaml***

```
web:
    container_name: "web"
    environment:
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
    env_file:
      - .env
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ../app:/home/app
      - ../media:/home/media
      - ../misc:/home/downloads
    command: ["/home/app/start.sh"]
```

***dockerfile***

```
# Fetch the base image
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install python3 and pip3
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip git libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev openjdk-8-jdk libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 curl nano wget unzip

# Install pip3 lib
COPY pip3-requirements.txt /pip3-requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r pip3-requirements.txt

# Copy Code
ADD . /home/app/
```

**Details:**

***docker version:***
`Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c`

***docker-compose version:***
`docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown`

***base image of dockerfile:***
`ubuntu:18.04`

Comment: Can we please see the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile, likely it is an issue with start.sh not being in the expected location or not being copied across - can only guess without those 2x files

Comment: @mikey, updated the post with those files.

Comment: I could be getting this wrong, if you could provide the output of an 'ls . ..' from within the folder housing the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml would also help.

Comment: Any luck/did that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

I'm attempting this again via example, as I think it really does come down to the project structure, sorry if my prior attempt was confusing.

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ADD . /home/app
```

And a docker-compose.yml file:

```
web:
    container_name: "web"
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ../test:/home/app
    command: ["/home/app/start.sh"]
```

With a directory structure of:

```
./test
    docker-compose.yml
    Dockerfile
    start.sh
```

Then I can run:

```
chmod +x start.sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

What can be useful to troubleshoot this is to run:

```
docker run -it web bash
> ls -al / /home /home/app
```

I hope that helps, I suspect the script isn't being placed into `/home/app` as the error you are getting is stating.